# Ajax - return result of PHP script to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Probably a stupid question - but I have a form which allows the user to submit one number. Using that number, I use a 3rd party API to process the request and in return I receive an array of arrays.

I am trying to do this request via Ajax - submit the request via Ajax, and I have the return working. However, I don't want to parse the 2D array returned in Javascript - how do I parse it in PHP?

`index.php`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){
      $(".nd-tracking").submit(function(){
        var data = {
          "action": "test"
        };
        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "nd-request.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
          data: data,
          success: function(data) {
            $(".the-return").html(
               "<pre>" + data["json"] + "</pre>"
                // $.each(data, function(key,value) {
                //     console.log(value.code[0] + ' ' + value.date[0] + ' ' + value.time[0]) 
                // })
            ); 
          }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="nd-request.php" method="post" class="nd-tracking">
    Consignment ID: <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Consignment ID" name="consignmentid"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
    </form>

    <div class="the-return">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`nd-postrequest`

```
<?php

if (is_ajax()) {
if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
  $action = $_POST["action"];
  switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
    case "test": test_function(); break;
  }
}
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}
/*
*   Sending the Tracking Request via XML to NetDespatch
*   input - URL where the request is being submitted
*           XML request
*   returns XML response from NetDespatch        
*/
function sendTrackingRequestToNetDespatch($URL, $xml_data) {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $result;
  }

/*
*   Count the number of nodes in the tracking node (each node is a stage of the delivery proces)
*   input - parsed XML by simplexml_load_string
*   returns an integer that is a number of stages a consignment has been through
*/

function numberOfStages ($xml){
  foreach ($xml->response->gettrackresponse as $stage) {
          $num_of_stages = $stage->count();
  }
  return $num_of_stages;
}


function test_function(){
$return = $_POST;
      $consignmentID = $_POST["consignmentid"];
      $xml_data =
      'ndxml=<ndxml>' .
          'blahblah' . 
      '</ndxml>';

      $URL = "URLofRequest";

      // Submit XML request and grab response
      $output = sendTrackingRequestToNetDespatch($URL, $xml_data);

      // Parse the XML response
      $xml=simplexml_load_string($output) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

      // Check 'status' from XML response - if OK, proceed
      $status = $xml->response->status;
      if ($status == "OK - Data to follow") {

          // Count the number of stages the consignment has passed
          $num_of_stages = numberOfStages($xml);
          // We define an empty array which will be filled by using the while loop for each stage
          $stages = array();
          while ($num_of_stages > 0) {
              $num_of_stages--; // decrementing first as the XML array is zero based 

              // Buidling a 2D array for each stage and sub-info
              $stages[$num_of_stages]['code']         = $xml->response->gettrackresponse->tracking[$num_of_stages]['code'];
              $stages[$num_of_stages]['date']         = $xml->response->gettrackresponse->tracking[$num_of_stages]->trackdatetime->date; 
              $stages[$num_of_stages]['time']         = $xml->response->gettrackresponse->tracking[$num_of_stages]->trackdatetime->time;
              if (isset($xml->response->gettrackresponse->tracking[$num_of_stages]->{'track-event'})){
                  $stages[$num_of_stages]['trackEvent']  = $xml->response->gettrackresponse->tracking[$num_of_stages]->{'track-event'};
              }
              if (isset($xml->response->gettrackresponse->tracking[$num_of_stages]->{'carrier-event'})){
                  $stages[$num_of_stages]['carrierEvent']  = (string)$xml->response->gettrackresponse->tracking[$num_of_stages]->{'carrier-event'};
              }
          }

          // reverse the results array so that we can display the results starting from the first event
          $return = array_reverse($stages);

      } elseif ($status == "No order found for the given consignment number") {
          $return .=  "No order found for the given consignment number.";
      }

$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
echo json_encode($return);
}
?>
```

`the response`

`[{"code":{"0":"BKD"},"date":{"0":"2016-06-30"},"time":{"0":"08:51:33"},"trackEvent":{"0":"Magda Sliwa"}},{"code":{"0":"ACC"},"date":{"0":"2016-06-30"},"time":{"0":"11:59:43"},"trackEvent":{"0":"Depot"},"carrierEvent":"accepted"},{"code":{"0":"CRD"},"date":{"0":"2016-07-01"},"time":{"0":"09:56:00"},"carrierEvent":"Closed \/ carded"}]`

I want to take this response and process it via PHP.

Comment: I can supply code examples if needed?

Comment: So you're sending a request to a 3rd party API which returns a 2-dimensional array and you wish to parse this in PHP rather than JavaScript?

Comment: _I can supply code examples if needed?_ Yes that would be a pre-requisite for any sort of useful answer

Comment: Yes. Basically I parse the API response via PHP and my return value is a 2D array. I then want to loop through that array via PHP in the index.php

Comment: What do you mean by _Parse it_ are you looking to get just a couple of data items out of it to return to the pages javascript?

Comment: @RiggsFolly please see update

Comment: Also post `nd-request.php`

Comment: That is a particularly dumb JSON structure you are getting back from the API. Is it your API or someone elses

Comment: You need to remove all those unnecessary bottom level classes that have a property called `[0]` Try this idea `$stages[$num_of_stages]['code']         = $xml->response->gettrackresponse->tracking[$num_of_stages]['code'][0];`

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work - I get the same response

Comment: Regardless - is there any way to push this out of <script> and back into PHP for processing?

Comment: Well that depends on what you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to loop through it and echo the results

Comment: ECHO EXACTLY WHAT RESULT. How do you want to chnage what you have got into what you want i.e. What is it you actually want to pass back to the page

Comment: I need to show 
`time` - `date` - `code` for first item
`time` - `date` - `code` for second item
etc. this is a consignment tracking result

Comment: So you have to pass an array from PHP to javascript regardless. Work out how to get a data item from `$xml->response->gettrackresponse->tracking[$num_of_stages]['code']` and not another object or array. Then the array of objects you are already building will be simple to process in javascript

Comment: Also look at the API doc. Maybe they have an option to return the data as a JSON String rather than XML which would simplify your processing as well as make the data easier to deal with

Comment: API is very outdated, only works with XML and no docs. I've created a PHP parser and that works but want to make it more elegant with Ajax. However, not sure I'll be able to do this based on our chat.